# Remove x-axis scroll from website

Tags: html, css

I have website i.e. [onlinecliniq.com](http://www.onlinecliniq.com/) There is scroll at x-axis. I have checked complete HTML and found that container below menu i.e **usman_content_topb** is going outside of and causing the scroll. Can you please help me remove it.

I think problem is due to width:1060px; in internal div i.e. **usman_main**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
html,body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: This will fix it but I suspect he is using row not wrapped inside a container somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `width: 100%` should do the trick. Better said:

```
#usman_content_topb {
    min-width: 960px;
    min-height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    background: transparent none repeat scroll 0px 0px;
    padding: 20px 0px;
    margin-top: 165px;
}
```